# Mostrar resultado de consulta en Label

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo una clase conexión con este método:

```
    public void fechaParaLabel()
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            string consulta = "SELECT TOP(1) FechaDesde, FechaHasta, MES, ANO " +
                              "FROM periodos " +
                              "WHERE IdProcesoAdmin=2 AND " +
                              "FechaHasta IS NOT NULL " +
                              "ORDER BY IdPeriodo DESC";
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(consulta, sqlConnection))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
                {
                    using(DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                        string FechaDesde = dataTable.Rows[0]["FechaDesde"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Y me gustaría mostrar eso en un label, cabe destacar que puedo hacerlo desde el `Form` pero no quiero ocupar el `Form` con código de tipo conexiones. Quiero llamar al método y mostrar el resultado en un label.

```
    private void menu1item1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cmbTipoPlan.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        cargarTipoPlan();
        cargarFecha();
    }

    private void cargarFecha()
    {
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        string texto = conexionSQL.fechaParaLabel();
    }
```

¿Alguien me podría decir cómo lo hago? Puesto que la línea : `string texto = conexionSQL.fechaParaLabel();` no funciona debido a la conversión de `string` - `void`

Comment: Entonces cambia la firma del método para que en vez de void te devuelva un string. private string fechaParaLabel() {....} además si vas a utilizar un solo valor de la consulta, porque haces una select a varias columnas, hazlo solo a la que necesitas. Y en vez de utilizar un sqlAdapter, utiliza un string FechaDesde = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar() dentro de FechaParaLabel [ExecuteScalar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por qué no transformas la función para que devuelva un string así no tenes que hacer ningún tipo de conversión

```
   public String fechaParaLabel()
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            string consulta = "SELECT TOP(1) FechaDesde, FechaHasta, MES, ANO " +
                              "FROM periodos " +
                              "WHERE IdProcesoAdmin=2 AND " +
                              "FechaHasta IS NOT NULL " +
                              "ORDER BY IdPeriodo DESC";
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(consulta, sqlConnection))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
                {
                    using(DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                        string FechaDesde = dataTable.Rows[0]["FechaDesde"].ToString();
                        return FechaDesde;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Y después simplemente

```
myLabel.setText(fechaParaLabel());
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, no se porque no se me había ocurrido. Muchas gracias

Comment: Suele pasar! No hay problema compañero